# What does the "make screencast" button do?

Tags: interface

In the info view header, under *Window* there is an option to "Make Screencast".

[image]

It's tooltip says

> Capture a video of the active area or whole Blender window.

When I click it a circle appears over my mouse and an option to stop the capture appears on the right of the header.  When I click the button everything goes back to normal and nothing happens.

So what does this button do?  If it really made a video of what I did where did it save it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Make Screencast* button allows you to save all actions you make in the Blender window to a video file.

From [the doc](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/screenshot.html):

> Screencasts will record your actions over time either as a video or sequence of image files. The type and location of the output is determined by the settings in the *[Output panel](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html)* of the [Render context](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/properties/introduction.html#properties-context-render) window.

So the screencast video is saved to wherever you set under the *Render* tab > *Output* rollout.  It will also use whatever settings you set there for video output format as well.

[image]

Comment: I had the brilliant idea of searching the docs, what a concept!  When all else fails...

Answer (score 8):

***Make Screencast*** allows you to capture all actions you've done in Blender and save it to the desired location with desired file format.
[image]

Choose the location you want the record to be saved, desired file format and its quality.
[image]

When you are done with recording press ***Capture*** button on the upper menus bar.
[image]

Comment: Hehe, guess I am a bit late :). Seems you've figured it out by yourself...